# How to get 2 elements with flexbox to fix to window height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an Angular app with the containing element as flexbox, I want the 2 elements inside the only use the window without causing a scrollbar, this works as expected in Chrome but its not working in Edge browser or Firefox. How can I get the menu and main view to stack vertically and use the window height?

```
my-app {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

The 2 components:

```
app-menu {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: lightcoral;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

app-my-view {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

To see it work properly check the example in Chrome. In Edge and Firefox the `app-my-view` extends outside the `my-app` element and causes the scrollbar.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/2-column-scroll-v2?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: add `min-height: 0` to `app-my-view`? see https://stackblitz.com/edit/2-column-scroll-v2-q6onqc

Comment: @kukkuz I don't understand why that is making it work. Without min-height the elements extend outside container then adding min-height gets rid of the problem... Is it some kind of browser fix for firefox and edge?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247140/why-dont-flex-items-shrink-past-content-size